# Laravel Cache::put() weird behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, I am implementing a middleware in laravel which checks API connectivity every 5 mins but I am having some wierd behaviour.

I implemented the following code to test but when I refresh the page it always returns '**Valid**' it never returns '**Renewed**', but if I move the return response expired on top of the Cache::put statement it does return '**Expired**' but ofcourse the cache will not be set.

This code is inside a middleware not a controller, I am returning responses just for debugging purposes. In reality the the behaviour would be that if the cache has the key it would move onto the next middleware.

```
if ( Cache::has('apicheck') ) {
    return Response::make( 'Valid' , 200 );  
}
else
{   
    //Make API Check Here and Set Cache-apicheck if success
    Cache::put('apicheck', 'success', 5);
    return Response::make( 'Renewed' , 200 );    
}
```

Comment: `but I am having some wierd behaviour.` What is it ?? I don't see anything weird in your code.. It is completely okay. It will always return `Valid` for next 5 minutes, once it hits the middleware and has the key of `apicheck`. And on 6th minute, it will return `Renewed`..

Comment: That is just it, It never returns 'Renewed' even after the key expires. The weird behaviour is that the key expires it is then renewed and the 'Renewed' is never returned. It always returns 'Valid'